# i'm getting "Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type" in map function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

my code looks like this:

```
const itemList = useSelector((state:RootStateOrAny)=>state.itemList)

let render = itemList && itemList.length > 0 ? 
 itemList.map(item => {return 
  <div 
      <img  
        src={item.url} 
        alt="image" 
      />
   </div>}) : <div> no content </div>
```

i think i am making some mistakes with typescript. i tried to read up but being new to typescript i couldn't understand. is there anyone more experienced who can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is the `RootStateOrAny` type.  You need to be using the type of **your app's state**.  Probably you want to create a typed version of `useSelector` instead of writing `(state: RootState)` every time.  This doc explains what to do: https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/usage-with-typescript#standard-redux-toolkit-project-setup-with-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the type of the `item` variable in

```
itemList.map(item => ...)
```

You could fix it by defining a type for that variable.

```
type MyItem = { url: string }

itemList.map(item: MyItem => { ... })
```